# MOSFET equivalent

Tags: mosfet

I'm trying to find an equivalent MOSFET to the model MDU1513 to fix my graphics card, but the closest spec I have is PH7030AL.

I have other MOSFETs but I think they're not compatible which are PH2530AL and B09N03.

In my very limited experience (amateur) after reading the tables, I think the PH7030L is within close tolerance to my faulty MDU1513 but I might be wrong. What do you think folks?

Edit: I need to replace four MOSFETs but I have two of PH7030AL two PH2530AL and five of B09N03

Comment: Fairly similar. But while the pinouts the same, the package is not. Will a SOT669 fit on the pad for a PowerDFN56? It's close enough but different enough that I can't tell by just looking at the dimensional drawings.

Answer (score 1):

Reference MOSFET: [MDU1513](https://www.magnachip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/MDU1513-1.pdf).

Alternatives:

- [PH7030L](https://chipmaster.pro/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/PH7030AL-22294.pdf): Electrically, it is quite close. Mechanically, there are slight differences between the two. The package's outer dimensions are quite close but the pad layout is not the same. The dimension of the tab (mounting base) is different.
- [PH2530AL](http://pdf.tixer.ru/169389.pdf): Electrically, total gate charge (Q<sub>tot</sub>) and the input capacitance (C<sub>iss</sub>) are higher. These may lead to higher driving losses. Mechanically, same as PH7030L.
- [B09N03](http://www.datasheet-pdf.com/PDF/B09N03-Datasheet-ExcellianceMOS-1254749): Electrically, total gate charge and input capacitance are lower but the on-resistance (R<sub>DS-on</sub>) is higher. This may lead to higher conduction losses. Mechanically, it is a quite close match.

---

PS: If the MOSFETs are part of the multi-phase buck converter of the core supply circuitry then, even if you can successfully replace the broken MOSFETs with the ones you already have, they too may eventually break down.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I soldered two PH7030L and two PH2530AL and tested the card for about 2 hours and it's working properly. Due to my limited knowledge, I can't fully understand "higher driving losses" and the PS note. Is there a danger on the GPU or Memory? Or the other Mosfets?

Comment: @SammySam `I can't fully understand "higher driving losses" ...` To turn a MOSFET on its gate should be charged. Energy is required to charge a MOSFET's gate. And this creates a loss. The higher the total gate charge, the higher the driving losses. `... and the PS note` Well, what I was trying to say is, that if you don't know the root cause (i.e. what happened and those MOSFETs died) and don't fix it then the new MOSFETs too may die eventually. If these MOSFETs are part of the core supply regulator (idk) extra care should be taken because they are at the heart of the entire graphics card.

Comment: The 4 MOSFETs I installed in the morning just died while rendering a few moments ago. I think yes I they do feed the core which is a 4 phase as I found out. I guess there's something like the Driver Gate chip which is making them fail if I understood correctly from watching repair videos. The problem is that the card is very rare where I live, it's a Zotac GTX 970 AMP Extreme Core Edition.

Comment: I noticed something very strange is that when I precisely spray a small amount of contact cleaner on the related Gate Driver the short is gone and the resistance of the MOSFET gradually gets back to normal, but when I tried to power the card again the short is back. I did that about 3 times and the short goes away every time with the contact cleaner on the Gate Driver. How can that happen? Does that mean the Gate Driver is faulty as well?

Comment: @SammySam probably. That's why I said "Find the root cause or else the problem will never go".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I learned a lot. I will try to replace these Drivers if I can find similar ones.